Apple Application for transferring "filtered photos" (eg portrait) that avoid aae files
I know that with AirDrop when I share/transfer photos from my phone that have portrait or some other filter/effect applied to the image that it is the rendered/filtered image which gets copied over to my macbook. In short they copy over as a standalone rendered image.
However my workplace has blocked AirDrop sharing when the target is the macbook that receives the files for reasons of security management. I'm wondering is there an alternate means that MacOS or iOS makes available to transfer over final rendered images from a phone to the macbook?
Image Capture
I'm aware of Image Capture as a candidate to transfer photos, however it falls short because I basically don't want to bother with aae files and to have to recreate the rendered effect on my base images. Is there a mode that Image Capture can be enabled under which transfers the rendered image rather than the base unedited image paired with its *.aae plist file?
Going into further detail on this for the unfamiliar you get an Apple Adjustments and Edits Sidecar or aae file copied over in lieu of a rendered image for Portrait photos and perhaps others. These aae files have an ASCII data block which presumably maps as an input to the filter algorithm to recreate the effect on the base image. They are text files which look something like this...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>adjustmentBaseVersion</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>adjustmentData</key>
    <data>
    ...ASCII BLOCK HERE...
    </data>
    <key>adjustmentEditorBundleID</key>
    <string>com.apple.camera</string>
    <key>adjustmentFormatIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.photo</string>
    <key>adjustmentFormatVersion</key>
    <string>1.11</string>
    <key>adjustmentRenderTypes</key>
    <integer>2050</integer>
    <key>adjustmentTimestamp</key>
    <date>2024-04-10T18:21:05Z</date>
</dict>
</plist>


However I don't want to recreate the rendered photo from its base inputs. I'm worried that AirDrop is the only application which shares uncompressed images that display on the Macbook exactly as they do on the Photos app on the phone, ie fully rendered. I want the rendered copy to transfer to the Macbook and I know of no other way to do so beyond AirDrop which is unavailable to me unfortunately.

Can‘t you just send the image by mail?

I don't think that would preserve the file attributes with the timestamps and all that. Anything distributed over the browser creates a new file essentially. Feels like only things that are mounted to the file system are capable of preserving file attributes.

I may have missed the part about file attribute preservation in the question. Anyway, any file transfer results in a new file, it is up to the transfer method used to preserve metadata.

yah it's not listed in the Q but is something I track and pay close attention to because it makes large scale photo management easier to work with when using the base OS to do image searches where you don't need recourse to the EXIF data. Finder doesn't even expose the exif data to even do a search with which really stinks at times. Windows lets you add that column in File Explorer, but all the better when you can avoid EXIF entirely by having accurate file attributes to begin with.

I think there may be trouble with iOS mail doing inline image embedding vs proper file attachments too. Maybe a zip file for the batch? I forget the behavior exactly but my last memory is iOS mail does images inline in the body of the email html rather than as a separate file attachment. That may be configurable though by choosing a different app for the email client to go looking for the files. Nevertheless email servers limit email payload size to like 10MB or so; but this technique could work for a handful of images though if faced with nothing else.

How should people be able to provide answers to your question if you don‘t list the requirements you have?

just like any other answer--they get posted and the comments feedback on any missed details to hopefully update the answer with the related pros & cons, limitations, and other relevant details. Email looks like a worthwhile workflow to document, post an email answer and some screenshots from iOS. There's actually share options and other behavior worth documenting it seems now that I snoop around a bit.

I just noticed some behavior finally that I never noticed before. Taking one portrait photo that I shot recently I actually see an E copy and a non E copy in Image Capture. This presumably means edited. Notice the IMG_E5765.JPG vs IMG_5765.JPG in the screenshot below (interestingly enough in my original question I never even noticed the IMG_E5310.JPG copy at all).

When I transfer the files after pressing the Download button I get an edited copy with a blurred background and a non edited copy with a regular appearance. When I diff the image I see mostly everything is identical in the EXIF data apart from this Rendering int with value 8 seen with the edited copy and also the Marker note which differs in a way I don't understand since it's a blob of data. The visual diff shows as expected with the background blurred in the edited copy (seen on the left in the diff tool).

The reason I never noticed this before was because I always had attention on the transferred copies and not the line item rows in Image Capture. Image Capture only presents a thumbnail view which isn't enough to review your images. However once transferred over to Finder where you can do the enlarged review of your images you discover that Apple made the bad decision to prefix with an E rather than to suffix the file names. As a result you never see these photo files side by side in the normal sorting by name view. I'm going to write a bash script to rename all the IMG_EXXX.JPG files to go instead as IMG_XXXE.JPG which will keep families of images contiguous with one another. Apple designers miss details like this I've noticed--you want prefixes for families of things and suffixes for variants. This should have been a variant naming convention not a family based one. When you transfer over large batches of images it's very unlikely you'll see the two files side by side. I was also lucky to sort by Date within the Image Capture app which makes more sense because you see all the images an your device and with Apple only reserving 4 digits for the file name sorting by Name gets you into non chronological mixed up stuff very quickly.

Bash command to rename files
# CD into the folder the images are stored
cd folder_w_images

# Execute this command to rename all the files
find . | grep 'IMG_[^0-9]' | sed -E 's/IMG_(.)([0-9]+)\.(.*)/mv IMG_\1\2.\3 IMG_\2\1\.\3/' > rename_edit_files.sh; bash rename_edit_files.sh; rm rename_edit_files.sh

